# Child width in LinearLayout

Tags: android-linearlayout, android

I have a `LinearLayout` that I use to make a box to display a date:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/date_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_frame"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_rowSpan="3"
    android:minWidth="65dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="20sp"
    />
    <View
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/day_of_week"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

It makes a nice little box (this is without the `View` in the above code): [image: Date Box]

When I put the `View` in there, it stretches the box all the way across the screen, I just want to draw a line across the width of the box without changing its width, why does it not work as I have it coded?  Shouldn't the `android:layout_width="match_parent"` simply match the width of the containing `LinearLayout`?  Why does it work for the two `TextViews` and not the `View`?

The `LinearLayout` is contained in a `GridLayout`.

I've also found that if I replace the `View` with a `TextView`, but leave all else exactly the same, it works as I want it to and doesn't expand to fill the whole screen width.  Why does TextView work like I expect and View not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu don't have a layout_width or layout_height on the LinearLayout.  So its width and height are undefined, and probably defaulting to fullscreen.  You need to set its width to wrap_content.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `LinearLayout` is contained in a `GridLayout` that handles its width.  If I leave out the `View`, it works just fine, only when I put the `View` in there does it expand to fill the whole screen width...

Comment: Ah.  My guess is that View has some odd issues because it was never really meant to go in a layout-  it has no data to draw, it really should have been an abstract class when you think about it (in fact I'm surprised it isn't).  If you were just using it to space out views you'd do better to use padding on one of the elements.

Comment: I just want it to show a horizontal line, not worried about spacing.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Then I'd use an ImageView set to an xml drawable of a line.  Using a generic view is really not the right way to do it.